# SPFx Application Customizer - hide a <div>

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I've written an SPFx Application Customizer which runs fine and I can log to the console with it.

However when I try to hide the "SharePoint" link in the top left of the page in SPO I get the error below:

> Error: Failed to create application customizer
> 'ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer.ab3da44e-81af-4590-9bf3-b305f602265c'.
> Error information is 'Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'display')'.

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    let message: string = this.properties.testMessage;
    if (!message) {
      message = '(No properties were provided.)';
    }

    // Dialog.alert(`Hello from ${strings.Title}:\n\n${message}`).catch(() => {
    //   /* handle error */
    // });

    console.log('DefaultApplicationCustomizerApplicationCustomizer onInit...');

    console.log('get homeLink');
    let homeLink: any = document.getElementsByClassName('o365sx-appName');
    console.log('got homeLink');
    homeLink.style.display = "none"; 
    console.log('changed homeLink');
```

Comment: As an additional note to the answer from Nikolay: in my opinion it is better to use css to hide elements in SPO (insert a style tag with the css via code). Your webpart/application customizer can not break if Microsoft decides to change the class names. If you want to use Typescript, use the types (instead of any) and you would have seen the problem directly in your code. It would just not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a **list** of elements.
You need the first one:

`let homeLink: any = document.getElementsByClassName('o365sx-appName')[0]`;

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using this code:

```
let homeLink: any = document.getElementById("O365_SuiteBranding_container");
```

OR

```
let homeLink: any = document.querySelector("div#O365_SuiteBranding_container");
```

Check for more information: [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)